# Entity Framework 5 Code First self referencing many to many named relation

Tags: c#, ef-code-first, foreign-keys, entity-framework-5, code-first

I have tried different models and configurations without progress. Have search for this specific usage but no success, found close but not same.

I have a product that is related to other products, so far so good if only one relation, e.g. "Related products"
The problem comes when adding additional relations e.g. "Similar".

What I am after is a self-referencing named relation, ideally a three column foreign key table; ProductId, RelatedProductId, RelationId

A product can have multiple named relations and a relation has one or more products (the related ones). I would like to avoid defining the name of the relation multiple times.

One idea has been as follows:

```
public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Relation> Relations { get; set; }
}

public class Relation
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
```

Another idea has been using a special table:

```
public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ProductRelation> Relations { get; set; }
}

public class Relation
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ProductRelation> Products { get; set; }
}

public class ProductRelation
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    public virtual int ProductId { get; set; }
    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public virtual int RelatedProductId { get; set; }
    [Key, Column(Order = 2)]
    public virtual int RelationId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ProductId")]
    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("RelatedProductId")]
    public virtual Product RelatedProduct { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("RelationId")]
    public virtual Relation Relation { get; set; }
}
```

The above example is the wanted result layout, how I wish to access it when retrieved, most likely need to be created in that way.
The below seems to be more clean from a db perspective with a three column mapping table

My questions are:

- What is the recommended approach and why?
- How to set up the mapping with keys properly so the database understand the relations as far as possible?

Comment: Your first solution looks like it ought to work to me, what's actually happening?

Comment: The relations should be unidirectional, p1 -> p2 should not automatically become relation p2 -> p1.

Comment: I see. Doesn't seem like you could get out of having a "middle" table/entity in that case.  Maybe: ProductId, RelationId, Direction as a primary key?  Direction could be a bit (0 == Product -> Relation, 1 == Relation -> Product).  Not sure you will be able to get out of doing the joins yourself in code though.